# Embedding weather widget into info window of Google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, widget, infowindow

I am trying to embed a weather widget from http://www.weather.com/services/oap/weather-widgets.html into an Info Window of a Google map, such that when I click on a marker, the weather widget is open in the Infowindow.

The code for embedding the weather widget is as follows (for San-Francisco, CA):

and it works fine when I put it into HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width:270px;height:175px;border:1px solid blue;padding:10px">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USCA0987?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to use it in the following code that is supposed to show the widget in the InfoWindow on the Google map it does not work:

```html
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var cpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(37.770728 ,-122.458199 );
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: cpoint,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var info1 = '<div style="width:270px;height:175px;border:1px solid blue;padding:10px"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USCA0987?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget"></script></div>';

var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.770728 ,-122.458199 );
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
position: point1 ,
map: map,
title: "Click here for details"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1 , "click", function() {
infowindow.setContent(info1 );
infowindow.open(map,marker1 );
});
}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
</body></html>
```

All I do is I put that div into info1 Javascript variable. I am not sure whether I do anything wrong, or InfoWindow does not allow to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to figure this out using iframe tag. See my blog post [Weather forecasting with SAS-generated Google maps](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/05/07/weather-forecasting-with-sas-generated-google-maps/).

First, I created weather mini-pages:

```
%macro create_widgets;

  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(places));
  %let num  = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nlobs));
  %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

  %do j=1 %to &num;

    data _null_;
      p = &j;
      set places point=p;
      file "&proj_path\widgets\accuweather_com_widget&j..html";
      put
        '<html><body>' /
        '<a href="http://www.accuweather.com/en/' loc +(-1) '/' loczip +(-1) '/current-weather/' lockey +(-1) '" class="aw-widget-legal"></a>' /
        '<div id="' dataid +(-1) '" class="aw-widget-current" data-locationkey="' lockey +(-1) '" data-unit="f" data-language="en-us" data-useip="false" data-uid="' dataid +(-1) '" data-editlocation="false"></div>' /
        '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>' /
        '</body></html>'
      ;
      stop;
    run;

  %end;

%mend create_widgets;
%create_widgets;
```

Then I defined an InfoWindow and a custom marker for the Google map as:

```
put
   'var info' i '= ''<iframe style="width:400px;height:360px;" src="widgets/accuweather_com_widget' i +(-1) '.html">'';' /
   'var point' i '= new google.maps.LatLng(' lat ',' lng ');' /
   'var marker' i '= new google.maps.Marker({' /
      'position: point' i ',' /
      'icon: ''images/weather-icon.gif'',' /
      'map: map,' /
      'title: "Click here for weather details"' /
   '});' /
   . . .
```

The rest of the code is no different than in all other [Google Map with SAS](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/tag/google-maps/) series.

Comment: Please quote here some parts of the solution and don't give only a link.

Answer (score 0):

This widget makes use of `document.write` to inject style and markup .

`write` can't be used without possible undesired side-effects after a document has been loaded, but the infowindow opens after the document has been loaded.

Possible workaround:

Use a (hidden)iframe. 
Into the hidden iframe load the widget and when the iframe has been loaded

1. set the content of the infowindow to the node representing the widget
2. apply the style created for the widget to the current document

---

```
//an array with the details, I guess ou want more than 1 marker
//[locationname, latitude, longitude, widget-url]
infos = [
    ['San Francisco', 37.770728, -122.458199, 'http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USCA0987?template=GENXH&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget'],
    ['Atlanta', 33.7489954, -84.3879824, 'http://voap.weather.com/weather/oap/USGA0028?template=GENXV&par=3000000007&unit=0&key=twciweatherwidget']
]


function initialize() {


    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.3396955, -100.509996),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    //create the iframe
    var infoframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(infoframe);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //iterate over the infos-array 
    for (var i = 0; i < infos.length; ++i) {
        //create the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(infos[i][1], infos[i][2]),
            title: "Click here for the weather of \n" + infos[i][0],
            script: infos[i][3]
        });

        //click-listener
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            var that = this;
            infowindow.close();

            //when the  widget for this marker hasn't been parsed yet
            if (!this.get('content')) {
                //the window-object of the iframe 
                var win = infoframe.contentWindow;
                google.maps.event.clearListeners(win, 'load');

                //open document and write the widget-code
                win.document.open();

                win.document.write('\<script src="' + this.get('script') + '">\<\/script>');
                //observe the load-event of the iframe
                //will fire when widget is available
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(win, 'load', function () {

                    //store style and widget-node as marker-properties
                    that.set('style', document.adoptNode(win.document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0]));
                    that.get('style').id = 'weatherstyle';
                    if (!document.getElementById('weatherstyle')) {
                        var weatherstyle = document.createElement('style');
                        weatherstyle.id = 'weatherstyle';
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(weatherstyle);
                    }
                    that.set('content', document.adoptNode(win.document.body.firstChild));
                    //trigger the marker-click
                    //this will open the infowindow now
                    google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click')
                });

                win.document.close();

            } 
            //widget has been parsed, set infowindow-content and open it
            else {
                //inject widget-style into document
                document.getElementById('weatherstyle').parentNode.replaceChild(that.get('style'), document.getElementById('weatherstyle'))

                infowindow.setContent(that.get('content'));
                infowindow.open(that.getMap(), that);

            }
        });
    }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

---

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tvn4qtxL/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/tvn4qtxL/)